# generics between java and kotlin !! help me?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

Here is my code

[ Kotlin ]

```
internal abstract class Parent<out T, in V> constructor(
    tList: List<T>,
    vList: List<V>
) {

    abstract fun get(): List<T>
    abstract fun set(v: List<V>)

}
```

[ Java ] - it inherits kotlin class Parent.

```
final class Child extends Parent<Number, String> {

    public Child(
            @NotNull List<? extends Number> tList, 
            @NotNull List<? extends String> vList) {
        super(tList, vList);
    }

   @NotNull @Override
    public List<Number> get() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(@NotNull List<? extends String> v) {}

}
```

the Parent class has the Generics called T(out), V(in),

so I think..

the constructor of class Child should be..

```
public Child(
        @NotNull List<? extends Number> tList, 
        @NotNull List<? super String> vList) {
    super(tList, vList);
}
```

i.e. the second argument vList should be

```
List<? super String>
```

because the V of parent's Generic is 'in' but it's..

```
List<? extends String>
```

is there anyone can explain this? help me!

[Edited]...

```
public Child(
        @NotNull List<Number> tList, 
        @NotNull List<String> vList) {
    super(tList, vList);
}
```

It's possible.. the code in my question is just generated code from IDE..

Comment: Why not write both in Java and save yourself the headache?

Comment: Why not write both in Kotlin and save yourself the headache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, interface `List` is immutable, which means it is read-only.

Here is its signature:

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E>
```

So your constructor actually looks like this:

```
internal abstract class Parent<out T, in V> constructor(
    tList: List<out T>,
    vList: List<out V>
)
```

If you want put values to `vList` (which you stated by using `in`), you have to use MutableList interface:

```
internal abstract class Parent<T, V> constructor(
    tList: List<T>,
    vList: MutableList<in V>
)
```